CAS write timeouts after upgrading Cassandra to 3.11.17
facing timeouts on cassandra database after cassandra upgrade to 3.11.17.1 for some insert statements with CAS serial consistency
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.WriteTimeoutException: \
  Cassandra timeout during CAS write query at consistency LOCAL_SERIAL \
  (2 replica were required but only 1 acknowledged the write)

tried checking logs and n tpstats and n status and all debug stuff, everything is normal

java driver version iscom.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.9.0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks for posting a question! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

With limited information, all that can be said is that the nodes in your cluster are unresponsive most likely because they are overloaded.
The driver reported the WriteTimeoutException because not enough replicas acknowledged the write part of the CAS read-before-write within the write request timeout (write_request_timeout_in_ms).
The coordinator for the request needed 2 replicas to acknowledge the write but only 1 replica did. This means that the other replicas were too slow to respond and it's highly likely the write failed. If so, you should check for dropped mutations in the logs or the output of nodetool tpstats.
If you're seeing lots of dropped mutations, it indicates that the commitlog disks cannot keep up with the writes so you should consider increasing the capacity of your cluster by adding more nodes. Cheers!

I do not see any dropped mutations on the cluster, no spikes of cpu, I/O wait and disk I/O is good and memory is good, os load is also fine

nodetool netstats and node tool tpstats show no dropped mutations and only some gossip messages dropped

If you're seeing dropped gossip messages, it indicates that either (a) nodes are temporarily unresponsive, or (b) there are interruptions to network connectivity. Either of those would be a reason for the write timeouts reported by the driver. Cheers!

no dropped in or dropped out packets seen for the last 7 days

I have faced the same in 3.11.16. wondering which release causing this. I also do not have mutation pending etc. this might be common
